# how to make a stretched image fit a specific height

Tags: html, css

I have an image which is stretched horizontally but when stretched it looks like this:

[image]

How do I retain its original height while cropping it. I don't want to use `object-fit contain` cause it causes so many images to be cropped which doesn't look good.

This is my markup, and the image below, and it responds well on mobile but on wider screens it looks cropped to fit

```
 <img  class="img-responsive pad tyi abn"  src="<?php echo $er ?>" style="   display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; top:-1000% !important; background-size:cover   !important;   position:center center;   background-repeat:no-repeat;  max-height:710px !important;  vertical-align:baseline;  -webkit-filter: brightness(100%); -moz-filter:  brightness(100%); -ms-filter: brightness(100%) ; filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='0');  min-width:100% !important; width:100% !important; margin:0px !important;  overflow:hidden;" alt="Photo"> [The photo below][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
  height: 120px;
}

.cover {
  width: 260px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/

Comment: I have used object fit it crops the image and makes many of the image cropped to center which i don't want and also i have max height on the image tag 710 px @Raziasultana

Answer (score 0):

You have a few inline styles in your ìmg`tag that in combination are problematic. The actual problem is the combination of`width: 100%`and`max-height:710px !important;` -> that's the real problem: The height is autmatically calculated from the width (by the proportions of the image), but when the calculated height is more than 710px, it will be forced to be only 710px and the image proportion will be distorted.

The picture you posted is an example: It would actually be higher than 710px due to the given width, but is squeezed down to 710px.

So you can either remove that `max-height:710px` or remove the `width: 100%`. In both cases you will get the right proportions between width and height.

Comment: It only gives the size of the image but it is cropped horizontally @Johannes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.img-container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
    
.img-container img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtsjI.jpg">
</div>
```

Change the `height` on the parent container to whatever height you want and adjust the percentage on the `translateY` to vertically center the image

Comment: Thanks it works but when i collapse the view the tall images maintain absolute width but now  their height is distorted @Sergio Alen

Comment: So the answer is correct. That is another problem then. What do you mean by absolute width, there's no such thing in css